# Confused about arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a new javascript developer from lua and I have some confusion about arrays. I'm trying to build a simple 2d array but after the initialization I keep getting an error that the array is "undefined"

here's the code :

```js
    var board = [];
    
    function initBoard(){
     for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      board.push([]);
      for (var j = 0 ;i < 8; i++){
       board[j].push([]);
      }
     }
    }
    
    function checkSquare(x, y){
     if (typeof(board[x][y]) === ""){
      return false;
     } else {
      return true;
     }
    }
    initBoard();
    console.log(checkSquare(3, 3));
```

Here's the error : Cannot read property '3' of undefined`

Comment: `for (var j = 0 ;i < 8; i++){` looks wrong. Did you mean `j`?

Comment: Your loops build a threedimensional array even. Maybe you meant `board[i].push("")` or `board[i][j] = ""`?

Comment: It was a problem with my loops thank you to both of you!

Answer (score 1):

You need not only take a look to the loops, but also to the check of the value of an item of the array. The comparison with the result of [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) with an empty string is always `false`, because there is no data type in Javascript Which is an empty string.

For comparing the value, you could check with the value directly with a [Identity/strict equality operator `===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity). This checks the type of the left and right side and the value as well. For objects, it check if the object has the same reference.

```js
function initBoard() {
  var board = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    board.push([]);
    for (var j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      board[i].push('');
    }
  }
  return board;
}

function checkSquare(x, y) {
  if (board[x][y] === '') { // check if the item is an empty string
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

var board = initBoard();

console.log(checkSquare(3, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a little mistale you've made while initialising. You've misplaced `j` with `i`. Try this:

```js
var board = [];

function initBoard(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        board.push([]);
        for (var j = 0 ;j< i; j++){ //There was a mistake here
            board[j].push([]);
        }
    }
}

function checkSquare(x, y){
    if (typeof(board[x][y]) === ""){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
initBoard();
console.log(checkSquare(3, 3));
```

```
var board = [];

function initBoard(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        board.push([]);
        for (var j = 0 ;j< i; j++){
            board[j].push([]);
        }
    }
}

function checkSquare(x, y){
    if (typeof(board[x][y]) === ""){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
initBoard();
console.log(checkSquare(3, 3));
```

Comment: That creates a triangular array - I don't think that's what the OP wants

Answer (score -1):

Two main things, you have a typo in your second loop, it should be based on `j` not `i`
and when you are trying to initialize the second array you can't use push because board[j] is undefined and `push` is a method of an array

```
var board = [];

    function initBoard(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            board.push([]);
            for (var j = 0 ;j < 8; j++){
                board[j] = [];
            }
        }
    }

    function checkSquare(x, y){
        if (typeof(board[x][y]) === ""){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    initBoard();
    console.log(checkSquare(3, 3));
```